# IF Statement is setting a session attribute in NODE js and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, session

I am trying to do a log in page for a Uni project and am having difficulty as when trying to redirect user based on an access level the if statement is setting the Access Role before the function and so all traffic when first logged in gets redirected to the Admin page, refreshing the page makes the code work properly as that it when the code that gets the details from the database has finished running... Any help would be great thanks!

**LogInController**

```
const session = require('express-session');
var Login = require('../models/Login');

exports.checksLogin = (req, res) => {
    // Implement this method using the pupil model
    console.log(req.originalUrl + "POST Received with query: ", req.body)
    const {Email, Pswd} =  req.body
    Login.checkLogin(Email, Pswd)
    if(session.AccessRole='Admin'){
        res.redirect('/admin')
    }
    else{
    }
}
```

**Login.js** (Models)

```
exports.checkLogin = (Email, Pswd) => {
    var database = require('../dbConfig');
    database.then(con => {
        con.query("SELECT * FROM Pupils WHERE Email = '" + Email + "'AND Pswd= '" + Pswd + "'").then(([rows]) => {
            //console.log(rows)
            if(rows.length>0){
                
                session.LoggedIn=true;
                session.FirstName=rows[0].FirstName
                session.LastName=rows[0].LastName
                session.Email=rows[0].Email
                session.CourseCode=rows[0].CourseCode
                session.Pswd=rows[0].Pswd
                session.AccessRole='Student'

                console.log(session.Loggedin+ '1')


            }
            else {
                con.query("SELECT * FROM Staff WHERE Email = '" + Email + "'AND Pswd= '" + Pswd + "'").then(([rows]) => {
                    console.log(rows)

                    session.LoggedIn=true;
                    session.staffID=rows[0].staffID
                    session.FirstName=rows[0].FirstName
                    session.LastName=rows[0].LastName
                    session.Email=rows[0].Email
                    session.Role=rows[0].Role
                    session.Pswd=rows[0].Pswd
                    
                    if(session.Role='Admin'){
                        console.log(`Admin`)
                        session.AccessRole='Admin'
                    }else{
                        session.AccessRole='Staff'
                    }
                })
                
            }
        })
    })
}
```

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
var session = require('express-session');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// Middlewares
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({defaultLayout: 'main'}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars')
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}))


// Client routes
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.render('index'));

app.use('/admin', require('./routes/Admin'));
app.use('/login', require('./routes/Login'));


app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());



const PORT= process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server Started on port ${PORT} `));
```

**Login.js (Routes)**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

var Login_controller =  require('../controllers/LoginController');

// Use the login.handlebars template
router.get('/', (req, res) => res.render("login"));

// CRUD routes
router.post("/submit-login", Login_controller.checksLogin);

module.exports = router;
```

**Admin.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const router = express.Router();

var pupils_controller =  require('../controllers/PupilsController');
var staff_controller = require('../controllers/StaffController')



// Use the login.handlebars template
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log(session.LoggedIn)
    if(session.AccessRole=='Admin'){
    res.render("admin")
    }
    else{
        console.log(`No Entry`)
        res.redirect('/')
    }
    
});

// CRUD routes
router.post('/create-pupil', pupils_controller.createPupil);
router.post('/delete-pupil', pupils_controller.deletePupil);
router.post('/create-staff', staff_controller.createStaff)


module.exports = router;
```

**login.handlebars**

```
<p> Log In </p>


<form method="POST" action="/login/submit-login">
    <label for="Email">Email</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="Email" /><br>
    <label for="Pswd">Password</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="Pswd" /><br>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Using a MYSQL database, Node js and express

Thanks

Comment: Note, in your if statement you have `session.AccessRole='Admin'` which is an assignment not a comparison

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that the IF statement here must have double equal sign to compare, instead of that you are doing an assignation

```
const session = require('express-session');
var Login = require('../models/Login');

exports.checksLogin = async (req, res) => {
    // Implement this method using the pupil model
    console.log(req.originalUrl + "POST Received with query: ", req.body)
    const {Email, Pswd} =  req.body
    await Login.checkLogin(Email, Pswd)
    if(session.AccessRole == 'Admin') {
        res.redirect('/admin')
    } else {
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh thanks, this worked for not letting anyone have access however now the admin pages cannot access their page as the Login.js function still finishes after the if for some reason. Would you have any ideas about that?

Comment: Yes, in your checklogin function, you are calling an asynchronous function or returning a promise, so I recommend you to use async/await to solve that -- updated the answer code

Comment: Thank you this kind of solved the problem but Sorry I have to ask another question... I entered your code and i have to press the submit button on the log in page twice for it to redirect now, any ideas.

Comment: Probably the function is calling the checkLogin is not waiting for the promise, can you add that code as well so I can take a look of it? And some info regarding what framework you are using

Comment: Hi just updated the question with the rest of the code, if you could look id be really grateful

Comment: well your routing logic is a bit confusing, so by what I understand you have a main page where the user needs to click into a button or whatever, then it takes the user to the login page and in the post of the form you want's to redirect him into the admin page. am I right? if so, can you track the post request the first time you hit the button? it is doing the request successfully? also is the session being assigned before your if statement? or isn't and thats why you need to hit the button a second time?